# What is the difference between hanashi and monogatari?

Tags: word-choice

Both seem to mean story so I am wondering what the difference between them is.

Comment: はなし usually just means something closer to "discussion," whereas ものがたり is always a story about something specifically.

Comment: @Kurausukun You should make that an answer

Comment: How about comparing 「 **お** [話]{はなし}」 and 「[物語]{ものがたり}」 instead?　Both mean "tale"

Answer (score 10):

はなし（話） is the most basic word for any spoken content, that can be translated as *talk*, *story*, *rumor*, *argument*, *report*, *discourse* etc. as far as I can think of off the top of my head.

ものがたり（物語） is an old word that means "story-telling", and due to long-standing tradition 「X ものがたり」 becomes a fixed expression to say "tale of X", such as カンタベリー物語 *Canterbury Tales* or 二都【にと】物語 *A Tale of Two Cities*.

はなし has few special meanings, but we specifically refer to an *episode* of [rakugo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rakugo) by this word (in this case, it's usually written in kanji 噺).

Answer (score 3):

Generally, the comment of @Kurausukun to your question is correct.

Literally, 話｛はなし｝ *hanashi* is a story, and 物語｛ものがたり｝ *monogatari* is the noun form of 物を語る which means "to tell something" or "to tell a story".

To me, *monogatari* sounds having more meaningful or longer contents of a story than that of *hanashi*, and thus is more suitable to refer to the contents of a novel.